# Don't allows user to move from directory in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Someone knows if it is possible, in an openDialog or saveDialog, don't allow to the user to move to another directory? I am not able to find nothing about this.

An example, if I click a button and open de fileDialog in a specific folder, I don't want allow to the user to move to another directory. I am doing this to save and load files that are going to be in a specific directory and I don't want the user moves to other directories.

Thanks

Comment: You can't prevent the user navigating to a folder that they have permission to access (as far as I know, not with managed code anyway) but you can certainly validate the path of the selected file and make sure that it is in the folder you want.  Of course, if you don't want the user to see files in any other folder then you can always build the UI yourself and not use the standard dialogues.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple. If you don't want a user to be able to change folders then don't give them the ability to do so. In other words, don't use the `openDialog` and `saveDialog`.

The above dialogs are to allow you to select a folder and name, you appear to not need that.

If you still want the user to be able to specify a filename then you could simply have a textbox or an inputbox for the filename alone. Then do your relevant load/save error checks as you would normally.